# Is there a way to define a min-width on a jquery mobile website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to define a min-width on a page of a jquery mobile website but it seems not working. Am I wrong? Something like if the page width if less than 200px then place an horizontal scrollbar.

Thanks.

Comment: A link to the site would help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm not sure about other smart phones but the iPhone (older models) are 320 x 480. I really don't think there is a 200px width on a smartphone, but I could be way off on this as well.

Supported Browsers: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Also you could run media queries or add a breakpoint: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/mediahelpers.html

To utilize width breakpoints of your own, jQuery Mobile exposes the $.mobile.addResolutionBreakpoints function, which accepts either a single number or array of numbers that will be added to the min/max breakpoints whenever they apply.

```
//add a min/max class for 1200 pixel widths         
$.mobile.addResolutionBreakpoints(1200);

//add min/max classes for 1200, and 1440 pixel widths           
$.mobile.addResolutionBreakpoints([1200, 1440]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`min-width` is working in most modern mobile browsers. 
What is not available there are horizontal and vertical scrollbars - no such thing in principle.